# DialogResult problem in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, showdialog, dialogresult

I have a window that I open a few times as a ShowDialog.

Every time I open it I use the new keyword
in the first time i did:

```
var myWindow = new MyWindow();
myWindow.ShowDialog();
```

second time I open it from the MyWindow View Model class:

```
new MyWindow().ShowDialog();
```

in MyWindow code behind I have 2 events. one is when the user clcik ok and another when the user click cancel.

```
void OnCancel(){
  DialogResult = false;
}

void OnOk(){
  DialogResult = true;
}
```

The events fires from the View Model class form the ICommand Execute than bind to "ok" and "cancel" buttons of the window.

In the xaml I did this for the cancel button:

```
IsCancel = true;
```

And this for the ok button:

```
IsDefault = true;
```

in the first time that I opened the window I can set DialogResult = true, but after that when I try to set the DialogResult I've got exception "Dialofresult can set only after created window and shown as ShwDialog".

I also saw that the DialogResult is true after the first time is set to true and I think that the reason for the exception but I dont understand why is stay true if I closed the window and create a new one by using the new keyword...

Any suggestion

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
The problem is that once I clcik the "ok" button the DialogResult set to true and saty true and I can't set it to false.

**Edit**

Thanks everyone I solve the problem.

The problem was that I register to the View Model events ("ok" clicked and "cancel" clicked) and I remove the register when the user click "cancel" but not when he click "ok"...

Comment: Did you keep in mind that the Window closes after you set DialogResult and has to be re-opened?

Comment: this code works fine. Do you close the window after you set DialogResult = true ?

Comment: @hcb I thought its close after I click "ok" or "cancel" its wrong?

Comment: Where are you setting `DialogResult?`  You should post more of your code so we can understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `DialogResult` closes the window, so you can't set `DialogResult` again

BTW, `new Window().ShowDialog()` returns a `bool?`, not a window...

Comment: Can u explain? I missed somthing, why I cant set it again if I create a new window and display it as ShowDialog?. And I know its return bool?.

Comment: OK... could you show more code? From the code you posted, it's not very clear what the problem is

Comment: And you're assigning the result to a variable named `myWindow`, that's why I assumed you thought it returned a window...

Comment: @Thomas: the interesting part of `Window.DialogResult` is it doesn't make it obvious that setting it closes the window in the documentation. Also @Maya: if you set a button as `IsCancel` it will automatically set `DialogResult` to false, which may be why you're receiving the exception.

Comment: @sixlettervariables, as a matter of fact, `DialogResult` is *not* set automatically to false; it was the case in WinForms, but in WPF you have to set it manually. @Maya, sorry, I really don't know what is causing the problem...

Comment: @Thomas: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult.aspx) "By default, a dialog box is canceled when a user does one of the following: Presses *ALT+F4*; Clicks the Close button; Selects Close from the System menu. In all of these cases, `DialogResult` is false by default. A dialog box typically provides a special button to cancel a dialog, which is the button whose `IsCancel` property is set to true...will automatically close a window when either it is pressed, or when the ESC key is pressed. In either of these cases, `DialogResult` remains false."

Comment: @sixlettervariables IsCancel = true in my "cancel" button but the exception throw after I clicked "ok"

Comment: @Maya: if you put a breakpoint on `DialogResult = true;` how many times is it hit?

Comment: @sixlettervariables every time I clcik "ok". in the first time the DialogResult is null but after that is true. with the "cancel" button i think everything work fine.

Comment: @sixlettervariables now I saw that if I click the ok button and that clcik the cancel I get the exception becuase the DialogResult already set to true

Comment: @sixlettervariables, my mistake, I misremembered

Answer (score 1):

> I dont understand why is stay true if I closed the window and create
>   a new one by using the new keyword...

Because your intializing a new Window.  It returns True because as you already explained the first time it does.

Comment: but the previous window is disposed so why when I created a new one is DialogResult is true and not null?